# Auth token for evernote account configured in evernote app in android

Tags: android, oauth, evernote

I have a code working to search for content in evernote account using evernote sdk. Currently i get auth token for an account after the user gives her credentials and authorizes my app. But i dont want the user to type in credentials for an account that she has already configured in the evernote app in her android device. I want to get the auth directly from the evernote app(like dropbox and facebook sdk provides). So i want the flow to be,

1. Check for evernote app installed and an account is configured in it
2. If yes, then get the auth token from evernote app itself with only allow/deny page(note without showing the username/password page)
   3.If no, then go to the browser and continue in the normal way.

How can I do this? Any Help ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that the Evernote Android SDK supports yet.

The only supported authentication mechanism as of now is OAuth and that requires the user to enter their credentials on a webview and authorize your app.

The Evernote Android SDK is open source and you can look around the source on [github](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-android) and submit changes.

The functionality you propose would require the main Evernote app to register an Android Custom Account (just like Facebook's or Dropbox's apps do), and I'm not sure they have any plans to support that yet.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. We are investigating a tighter integration between the Evernote App and the SDK.